# How to use dplyr to conditionally change values in a column by group?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data like this:

```
g1 g2 var 
 1  a Yes 
 1  a No 
 1  a No 
 1  b Yes 
 1  b Yes 
 1  b Yes 
 2  a No 
 2  a No 
 2  a No
```

I would like to change all values in var to Yes if in each g1&g2 group, there is at least one Yes in var. I tried to use combinations of group_by and mutate, replace, ifelse with no success. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `if/else` instead of `ifelse`.  Grouped by 'g1', 'g2', `if` 'Yes' is `%in%` 'var', then return "Yes" or else return 'var'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(g1, g2) %>% 
   mutate(var = if("Yes" %in% var) "Yes" else var)
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   g1, g2 [3]
#     g1 g2    var  
#  <int> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 a     Yes  
#2     1 a     Yes  
#3     1 a     Yes  
#4     1 b     Yes  
#5     1 b     Yes  
#6     1 b     Yes  
#7     2 a     No   
#8     2 a     No   
#9     2 a     No
```

---

Or with `case_when`

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(g1, g2) %>% 
   mutate(var = case_when("Yes" %in% var ~ "Yes", TRUE ~ var))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(g1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), g2 = c("a", 
 "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a"), var = c("Yes", "No", 
 "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No")), class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(g1, g2) %>%
 mutate(var = ifelse(any(var == "Yes"), "Yes", "No"))

     g1 g2    var  
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     Yes  
2     1 a     Yes  
3     1 a     Yes  
4     1 b     Yes  
5     1 b     Yes  
6     1 b     Yes  
7     2 a     No   
8     2 a     No   
9     2 a     No
```

Here, if any value (per "g1" and "g2") in "var" is equal to `Yes`, it returns `Yes`, otherwise `No`.

Answer (score 1):

An extra line of code from the above two solutions, but using `ifelse` or `if_else` by creating a new column then deleting and renaming:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(g1, g2) %>% 
  mutate(var2 = if_else("Yes" %in% var, "Yes", "No")) %>% 
  select(-var, var = var2)
```

result:

```
     g1 g2    var  
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     Yes  
2     1 a     Yes  
3     1 a     Yes  
4     1 b     Yes  
5     1 b     Yes  
6     1 b     Yes  
7     2 a     No   
8     2 a     No   
9     2 a     No   `
```

Answer (score 0):

a non-case_when if_else way, fun

```
df1 %>% 
group_by(g1,g2) %>% 
arrange (g1,g2,var) %>% 
mutate(var=last(var)) 

 # arranged alphabetically, var values may be changed to the last value by groups -- Yes in this case


         g1 g2    var  
      <int> <chr> <chr>
    1     1 a     Yes  
    2     1 a     Yes  
    3     1 a     Yes  
    4     1 b     Yes  
    5     1 b     Yes  
    6     1 b     Yes  
    7     2 a     No   
    8     2 a     No   
    9     2 a     No
```

Comment: Thank you all very much!